# How to make a x number of parameters in a constructor java

Tags: java, sql, generics

Someone please show me how to make a generic class that creates an instance and lets you set and return the values later. Right now I have the below code, but as you can tell, its very messy and I'd like it to have x number of parameters from any number. Is there a short cut to this? Is there a way I can use HashMaps/HashTables/TreeMaps/etc. for this?

The reason I want to do this is to take a table from SQL (many different tables) and store them in a generic class and then a HashMap to store every row of the table. Then I want individual HashMaps for every table.

```
public class Data {
    String data1, data2, data3, data4, data5, data6, data7, data8, data9;

    public Data(String data1) {
        this.data1 = data1;
    }
    public Data(String data1, String data2) {
        this.data1 = data1;
        this.data2 = data2;
    }
    //Continue this process until there is a new constructor for every added parameter

    public Data(String data1, String data2, String data3, String data4, String data5, String data6, String data7, String data8, String data9) {
        this.data1 = data1;
        this.data2 = data2;
        this.data3 = data3;
        this.data4 = data4;
        this.data5 = data5;
        this.data6 = data6;
        this.data7 = data7;
        this.data8 = data8;
        this.data9 = data9;
    }
    
    //Repeat the next two lines for every variable in class
    public void setData1(String data1) {this.data1 = data1;}
    public String getData1(String data1) {return data1;}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As documented here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html#varargs
you can use "Arbitrary Number of Arguments"

Ie:

```java
public class Data {

    public Data(String... strings) {
        int numberOfStrings = strings.length;
        // String data1 = strings[0]; // first arg

    }
}

new Data(); // no parameter
new Data(new String[]{"data1"}); // one parameter
new Data("data1"); // one parameter
new Data(new String[]{"data1", "data2", "data3"});
new Data("data1", "data2", "data3");
```

Comment: Your example did not make the most sense to me, but I will still accept it because now I know what to search up and learn more about. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

While I'm not too sure on the SQL portion of the question, in general, the Builder Design Pattern is a great way to incrementally construct a class, rather than overloaded constructors, especially when you plan to have constructors with a large number of arguments.

To use it, we would create another builder class that can be used in building our object parameter by parameter. So for instance, for the Data class in the question, we could write:

```java
public class DataBuilder {
        // give them some default value in case they aren't initialized by the user
        private String data1 = "";
        private String data2 = "";
        private String data3 = "";
        private String data4 = "";
        private String data5 = "";
        private String data6 = "";
        private String data7 = "";
        private String data8 = "";
        private String data9 = "";
        
        public DataBuilder() {
            return new DataBuilder();
        }
        
        // returns a reference to itself to allow for chaining
        public DataBuilder data1(String data1) {
            this.data1 = data1;
            return this;
        }
        
        public DataBuilder data2(String data2) {
            this.data2 = data2;
            return this;
        }
        
        // and so on for all of the fields
        
        // a method to finally build the Data object from the DataBuilder
        public Data build() {
            return Data(data1, data2, data3, data4, data5, data6, data7, data8, data9);
        }    
    }

// build in one step with chaining
Data data = new DataBuilder().data1("data1").data2("data2").build();

// build in multiple steps
DataBuilder builder = new DataBuilder();
builder.data1("data1");
builder.data2("data2");

Data data = builder.build();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I want the constructor to pass on any number of parameters, even greater than 9. The forum has already been accepted